# Mr Abdulla earns 25 750 after his salary increase of 8.5%. What did he earn before the increase?

Tags: finance

I tried:
$$25 750 × 100÷8.5
=2188,75$$

$$25 750 - 2188,75
=23 561,25$$

Comment: no taxation involved ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be is original salary. Then $x \cdot (100+8.5)\%=x\cdot 1.085 = 25750$.

So $x=\frac{25750}{1.085}\approx 23733$.

Answer (score 0):

Let his initial salary be $n$.

We have 
$$n + \frac{8.5}{100}n = 25750$$

or 
$$\frac{108.5}{100}n = 25750$$

From here find $n$.

Comment: Add the missing $n$

Comment: Thanks @OrestesDante